# How to run a scheduled task to run a Flask app constantly?

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks

I feel pretty stupid asking this, but I am still kind of a newbie when it comes to server-related tasks.

I have a flask app that scrapes data from a website and checks a Postgres database if updates to the scraped data have to be made. Now I would like this task to run constantly because the data is going to be visualized on a website of mine.

I found the [Flask-APScheduler](https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler) lib for which I successfully run a scheduled task every 60 minutes. Now my short-minded question:

I run this task through an SSH connection to my server from my work PC. At the end of the day, I usually deactivate my virtual environment, close my console, and turn off my PC. Doesn't this also shut down my script and it will not update my database anymore?

Answer (score -1):

If you run the program inside a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux` (https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki). You can `detach` your tmux session from your ssh session and it will keep on running even if you close the ssh session. When you want to connect to the running session again, you can ssh back into the server and `attach` yourself to the background tmux session that you left running.

You can find the details for doing `attach` and `detach` here:
https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started#attaching-and-detaching